# C++ wrong output in Windows System

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

[enter image description here][1]I was a doing a very simple program to convert some values into any specific datatype with float of conversion of 3 precision value and double of 9 precision value. Here is my code :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
    float d;
    double e;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;

    cout << "\nUsing cin & cout\n" << endl;
    cout << a << endl << b << endl << c << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << d << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(9) << e << endl;

    cout << "\nUsing scanf and printf\n" << endl;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%ld\n", b);
    printf("%c\n", c);
    printf("%.3f\n", d);
    printf("%.9lf\n", e);


    return 0;
}
```

**Test case :-**

Input :- `3 12345678912345 a 334.23 14049.30493`

Correct Output :-

```
3
12345678912345
a
334.230
14049.304930000
```

This code passes all test cases , but it is giving wrong output in windows , i have tried in vscode , cmd , powershell. And working fine in online compilers and linux system.

Windows Output :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZdDl.png

Linux Output :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS0o2.png

How can i fix this in my system , please help.

Comment: Please post the output here directly, do not use external links.

Comment: `12345678912345` -- Does that fit into a `long`?  What is `std::numeric_limits<long>::max()`?  Also, you failed to mention the actual Windows compiler you're using.  VSCode and Powershell are not C++ compilers.  Use `uint64_t`, not `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, Windows type "long" is 32-bit size. And value "12345678912345" oversizes that size.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is to **always** control input operation, and you controlled none.

Here is a slight variation which at least allows to understand what is happening (using 32bits mode):

```
cin >> a;
if (!cin) {
    perror("Read error on a");
    return 1;
}
cin >> b;
if (!cin) {
    perror("Read error on b");
    return 1;
}
cin >> c;
if (!cin) {
    perror("Read error on c");
    return 1;
}
cin >> d;
if (!cin) {
    perror("Read error on d");
    return 1;
}
cin >> e;
if (!cin) {
    perror("Read error on e");
    return 1;
}
```

It gives:

```
Read error on b: Result too large
```

After a read error, the input channel will refuse to read anything else until its status has been cleared, so `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` will keep uninitialized values, hence your random results.

Workaround: just use 64bits mode as you do on Linux, or explicitely use `int64_t` 64 bits integers.

Fix: test that the input values are acceptables

Comment: The other workaround is to use `int64_t` instead of `long` for both 32-bit and 64-bit programs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Of course it is a possible workaround! I have edited my post with you comment. Thank you.